# Is HTTP/2 without SPDY possible yet?

Tags: spdy, http2, mod-spdy

Most browsers do support HTTP/2 and so do some servers.

Akamai for example offers a HTTP/2 testpage (*https://http2.akamai.com/*). When I visit this page in chrome and go to `chrome://net-internals/#spdy` the page is listed with the protocol h2-14 (HTTP/2 draft 14). But when I open the console on the akamai page and type `window.chrome.loadTimes()` the property `wasFetchedViaSpdy` is `true`. Why is this? The Akamai-page is HTTP/2, not SPDY, roght?

Another thing I dont get is this tutorial (*https://www.gatherdigital.co.uk/blog/how-to-setup-http-2-support/527*). It says:

*"How to setup HTTP/2 support (nginx, apache, plesk) [...]
Well, not quite HTTP/2, it's still mod_spdy."*

What is this HTTP/2 "over" SPDY thing? The reason for my question is i want to do some meassurement on which pages make use of which protocol.

Comment: Please ask the "offtopic question" as another question.  Keeps things focused if you ask one question per post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long story short: SPDY is dead, long live HTTP/2!

Asking whether "HTTP/2 is possible without SPDY" implies that HTTP/2 somehow depends on SPDY.  That isn't the case.  Instead, HTTP/2 and SPDY are so similar that many implementations are hacking their existing SPDY support to be HTTP/2.  There's also a lot of people who think HTTP/2 is SPDY, or get sloppy with their terminology.  They're different protocols.

[SPDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) is a non-standard (but open) extension to HTTP/1.1 by Google designed to speed up web site loading and interaction and eliminate a lot of the hacks people do to reduce the number of connections.  [HTTP/2 started with SPDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Genesis_in_and_later_differences_from_SPDY) and ran from there to create a new, standard protocol incompatible with both HTTP/1.1 and SPDY.

Many people treat SPDY and HTTP/2 as the same things, they're not.  There have been significant changes in the standardization process between HTTP/2 and SPDY so that SPDY and HTTP/2 are not compatible.  But they're really close, so many HTTP/2 implementations are just hacked SPDY implementations.

Many [web servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY#Server_support_and_usage) and [clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY#Client_.28browser.29_support_and_usage) implemented SPDY even though it wasn't a standard.  The performance gains were just too good to pass up.

Now that HTTP/2 is official, *SPDY has been officially deprecated in favor of HTTP/2* and will be withdrawn as a standard in 2016.  Web clients and servers are working to switch over.  While [the clients have adopted HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#Browser_support) very fast, [server support seems to be lagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2#HTTP.2FHTTPS_servers).

As of this writing, HTTP/2 has only been a standard for six weeks.  Give it some more time.  References to SPDY will be hanging around in HTTP/2 implementations, but that will be rapidly cleaned up.  Firefox 36.0.4's Network console properly reports the protocol version as HTTP/2.

As for finding out whether HTTP/2 is used, look at the HTTP response object, it should have the protocol used.